# Laravel Where clause, paginate and sortByDesc

Tags: php, laravel

I am working a project and I would want to use a where clause, paginate and then sort in the collection in specific order. I have tried the result below but keeps throwing the errors below Method:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vermex/resources/views/equipments.blade.php)

The Product model is where I am getting the data and  store in a variable called `$equipment`. If there is a better way of doing this, please help.

```
public function equipments()
    {
        $equipments = Product::where('product_category_id', 3)->paginate(2)- 
       >sortByDesc('id');

        return view('equipments', compact('equipments'));
    }
```

Comment: please add you view code, it will give us more information. The error could be in blade... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `orderBy` before the `paginate`

`$equipments = Product::where('product_category_id', 3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(2);`

`sortByDesc` is a collection method.

`paginate` will need to be last for links to be available in the blade view.

Comment: it is giving me this errorCall to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::sortByDesc()

Comment: @foreach($equipments as $equipment)
<h1>{{equipment->name}}
@endforeach